# Estimation of $\int_{z=R \cdot e^{i θ}} {e^{i \cdot z \cdot x}\over a^2+z^2} \,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Estimate this integral and find the limit while $$R\to\infty$$

$$\int_{z=R \cdot e^{i \cdot θ}} {e^{i \cdot z \cdot x} \over a^2+z^2} \,dz$$

I must find this while $z=R \cdot e^{i \cdot θ}$  and $0 \le θ \le \pi$.

Any ideas how to estimate this?

Comment: Provided that $x \geqslant 0$, the standard estimate (ML estimate?) quickly gives you the result.

Comment: it doesnt say anything  α>0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $|e^{izx}| \leq 1$ and $|a^2 + z^2 | \geq R^2 - a^2$ then

$$\Bigg|\frac{e^{izx}}{a^2 + z^2 }\Bigg| \leq M_R$$

where $M_r = \frac{1}{R^2 - a^2}$. As $L = \pi R$ it follows

$$\Bigg|\int_C \frac{e^{izx}}{a^2 + z^2}dz\Bigg| \leq M_RL = \frac{\pi R}{R^2 - a^2}$$

Now take the limit as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: it's says that the limit must be zero i cant underastand why

Comment: It's simple now.